# ELK: Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I followed this post to the "T":

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-centos-7

I am still getting this message. There is no drop down to select from. I googled and found something, this "something" seems to indicate that the configuration is correct:

```
[root@elk ~]# curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health status index   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   .kibana   1   1          1            0      2.5kb          2.5kb
[root@elk ~]#
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: IT appears that the client machine is able to connect to the elk server:

Comment: [root@sys1 logstash-forwarder]# tail -f logstash-forwarder.err


Launching harvester on new file: /var/log/messages
2015/09/24 18:07:59.061707 harvest: "/var/log/messages" (offset snapshot:0)
2015/09/24 18:07:59.061872 All prospectors initialised with 0 states to persist
2015/09/24 18:07:59.061968 Setting trusted CA from file: /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
2015/09/24 18:07:59.062270 Connecting to [192.168.1.235]:5001 (192.168.1.235)
2015/09/24 18:07:59.273827 Connected to 192.168.1.235
2015/09/24 18:08:04.223444 Registrar: processing 43 events

Answer (score 2):

So it seems some indices have to be manually entered for it to all start....
I followed the suggestion given here:
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2055

and added an entry, the chose the one which says "The index settings can also be defined with JSON:"

and restarted elasticsearch and followed the rest of the tutorial(working with the GUI):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-centos-7

It all works now. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

According to your `_cat` output, you don't have any indices in your ES server. You only have the `.kibana` index which stores the Kibana settings (searches, dashboards, etc).

You simply need to index some data in order to be able to work on them within Kibana. Make sure your logstash forwarders are running and shipping their logs. When that's done, your ES cluster will contain a new `logstash-...` index with your logs and you'll be able to visualize them in Kibana.

Comment: IT appears that the client machine is able to connect to the elk server: –  
     
[root@sys1 logstash-forwarder]# tail -f logstash-forwarder.err Launching harvester on new file: /var/log/messages 2015/09/24 18:07:59.061707 harvest: "/var/log/messages" (offset snapshot:0) 2015/09/24 18:07:59.061872 All prospectors initialised with 0 states to persist 2015/09/24 18:07:59.061968 Setting trusted CA from file: /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt 2015/09/24 18:07:59.062270 Connecting to [192.168.1.235]:5001  Connected to 192.168.1.235 2015/09/24 18:08:04.223444 Registrar: processing 43 events

Comment: It suddenly stopped working, this is the error message: {:timestamp=>"2015-09-26T07:28:25.143000-0400", :message=>"Got error to send bulk of actions: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];", :level=>:error}